# How to Split JSON Variant Column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have Json Variant column in the table. The column D has json variant value like this:

```json
[
   "[{\"xyz_id\":0001,\"abc_id\":10032,\"dis_name\":\" AP 20%\",\"dis_type_name\":\"Subtotal Dis\",\"disc_rate\":20.0,\"discount_total\":-1.0000}]"
]
```

We want to Create new Column E as xyz_id in that Column. we need to Strip out this values ()

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a valid JSON sample you've posted as copied from Snowflake?  I'm not to sure how to interpret it.  If I strip the outer `["` and `"]` the below code can be used to extract the field your looking for.

```
select parse_json('[{"xyz_id":0001,"abc_id":10032,"dis_name":" AP 20%","dis_type_name":"Subtotal Dis","disc_rate":20.0,"discount_total":-1.0000}]') COL_D,
       COL_D[0]:"xyz_id" COL_E;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion !! The data posted is correct. This data we are having in internal assigments. 
 The Column D have Variant like  this - 
[ "[{\"xyz_id\":0001,\"abc_id\":10032,\"dis_name\":\" AP 20%\",\"dis_type_name\":\"Subtotal Dis\",\"disc_rate\":20.0,\"discount_total\":-1.0000}]" ] 
Please help me with; Do we need to remove (\) or what would be the code be create the Column E with xyz_id.

Comment: Please update your question with minimum reproducible example to create the table containing your variant data.